# Custom Recovery Behavior

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using a diff drive robot for navigation and exploration in the environment. And i don't wanna using [recovery_behavior](http://wiki.ros.org/rotate_recovery) that in the [navigation](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation) package.  My aim is using my custom recovery behavior. How can i add my custom behavior to the navigation stack?
Thanks all.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340841/custom-recovery-behavior/) by [Murat](https://answers.ros.org/users/44145/murat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2019-12-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For just using custom recovery behaviors it is really simple, you just have to define them in the configuration of move_base :

```
recovery_behaviors:
   - name: 'conservative_reset1'
     type: 'clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery'
```

For the name you chose whatever you want but the type is the package where the recovery behavior is defined.

However if you want to write custom recovery behaviors you will need to make them implement the
`nav_core::RecoveryBehavior` interface and create the dedicated ros package.

I suggest you emulate what is done for the rotate recovery behavior that can be found in the navigation package:
[rotate](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/melodic-devel/rotate_recovery)

If you use catkin you can easily create the package structure with:
`catkin_create_pkg my_recovery roscpp nav_core`

---

Originally posted by [Alrevan](https://answers.ros.org/users/48145/alrevan/) with karma: 126 on 2019-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murat](https://answers.ros.org/users/44145/murat/) on 2019-12-31**:
Thank you so much!